# How to block Google Play store by router rule

Tags: firewall

Is there a way to block access to the google play store by a firewall rule? I'm trying to block access to the play store from our Wifi.

Comment: If you run a custom router firmware, e.g. OpenWRT or Tomato, or purchased a commercial consumer router with that OS option, or have an enterprise router, you would block it at the router, simply blocking the IPs would work. Unfortunately, if you have a regular consumer grade router, your options are limited. If you run Pihole or Adguard, you could attempt a DNS block by adding a rule for "android.clients.google.com".Some consumer routers will permit you to redirect some DNS entries to a custom lookup.

Answer (score -1):

1.Click "Start | Control Panel | System and Security | Windows Firewall."

2.Select "Advanced Settings." Click "Inbound Rules" to block an inbound port; click "Outbound Rules" to block an outbound port.

3.Select "New Rule." Choose "Port" from the options and then click "Next."

4.Choose "TCP" or "UDP," depending on which protocol the port uses. Click "Specific Local Ports."

5.Enter the port number or numbers into the available field; separate multiple numbers with a comma (e.g., "80, 20, 443"). Click "Next."I think port 5228 is used for Google Playstore.

6.Click "Block the Connection," then "Next." Choose which network location or locations – public, private or domain – the rule applies to and then click "Next."

7.Create a name for the rule and enter an optional description. Click "Finish" to block the ports on the computer.